# Set a variable using an array value based on another value in the same array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new.

I have a situation where I need to loop through an array, determine if a `$key` in that array has a value of `1`, then set a variable with the `$value` from different `$key` in the same array.

Here's what I mean.

I retrieve a JSON array from an API that looks, in part, like this:

```
   (
     [6] => Array
          (
            [element] => 191
            [position] => 7
            [multiplier] => 2
            [is_captain] => 1
            [is_vice_captain] => 
           )
      [7] => Array
           (
             [element] => 171
             [position] => 8
             [multiplier] => 1
             [is_captain] => 
             [is_vice_captain] => 
            )
```

What I want to do is loop through the array, determine whether the key `[is_captain]` has a value (1), and set a variable using the value from a different `$key`, specifically `[element]`.

For example, in the code above at `[6]`, I want to create a variable with the value of `[element] => 191` (191) if the value of `[is_captain]` is `1`.

Here's where I left things:

```
    for($i = 0; $i < count($players['picks']); $i++){
        foreach ($fpl_team_picks['picks'][$keys[$i]] as $key => $value){
                if (isset($key['is_captain'])){
                $variable = $value['element'];
            }
        }
     }
```

It doesn't work. I've tried the `isset` function and a series of array functions (`array_column` and others), and I'm stumped.

Comment: First you say if it is NULL or empty you want to set the variable, then later you say if it equals 1 you want to set the variable.  Which is it?

Comment: `if (isset($key['is_captain'])){` is obviously wrong and should issue an error. You probably meant to do `if (isset($value['is_captain'])){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was set in the right direction, so thanks immensely to the contributor for the help.

My original question didn't make clear that I was working with a nested array. My array snippet didn't show that. I've learned a lesson about completeness. (I'm new here).

Once I wrote the code block to handle the nested array and modified the conditional slightly, I was successful. Here's the final code which works:

```
$x = 0; 
$captainsArr = array($fpl_team_picks['picks']);

    foreach($captainsArr[$x++] as $value) {
        if (is_array($value)){
            foreach ($value as $index => $data) {
                if ($index === 'is_captain' && $data == 1){
                    $captain = $value['element'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array(
  6 => array(
    'element' => 191,
    'position' => 7,
    'multiplier' => 2,
    'is_captain' => 1,
    'is_vice_captain' => null
  ),
  7 => array(
    'element' => 171,
    'position' => 8,
    'multiplier' => 1,
    'is_captain' => null,
    'is_vice_captain' => null
  )
);
```

Set foreach loop on the array, set the values, loop through values, find the key value, `$index === 'is_captain'` and make sure it is set to `1` -> `$data === '1'`. If this is true define your variable.

```
foreach($arr as $value){
  foreach($value as $index => $data){
    if($index === 'is_captain' && $data === 1){
      $element = $value['element'];
      echo $element; // $element now holds the value where key = `element` if 'is_captain' is equal to `1`
    }
  }  
}
```

In your code, change the `$key['is_captain']` to `$key === 'is_captain'` then look for its value if it is a match with in that same conditional.

If the key is equal to target key `is_captain` and that keys value is equal to `1` get the value of the key set as `element` and assign it to your variable:

```
    if ($key === 'is_captain' && $val === 1)){
      $variable = $value['element'];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Thoroughly appreciated. 

What's weird is that I implemented your tips, wrote a block that looks like this:

            ```foreach ($captainsArr as $value) {
   foreach ($value as $index => $data) {
    if ($index === 'is_captain' && $data === 1){
     $captain = $value['element'];    
    }
   }
  }```

But my new variable ```$captain``` isn't recognized outside the loop. Nor can I echo it from inside.

Comment: is the loop inside a function or something?

Comment: No, I ensured that the ```foreach``` loop is on its own. I'll keep hacking away. Thanks for your help, Dale.

Comment: If I remove the ```if``` statement inside the loop, the ```$variable``` is set and I can access it outside the loop. It's the wrong value of course, but at least it exists and can be used. So it seems to be something with the conditional.